# How can I reorganize the way the thumbnails display of this page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the link of the page: http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/examples/5/

What I want is similar to the page from the link above.  But instead of the thumb nails display on the bottom of the bigger image, I want them to be display on the right side (where the whole paragraph of writing/description is located) and switch the whole paragraph of writing to the bottom of the bigger image where the thumbnails are located.

Could someone show me how I can reorganize this page please.  Thank you very much!

You can see what i've got so far at: http://www.jsfiddle.net/11mini11/EQBXF/1

For CSS

```
body{background:url(../img/body-bg.jpg) top left repeat; font-family:"Segoe UI",Calibri,"Myriad Pro",Myriad,"Trebuchet MS",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;}

h1 {font-size:1.2em; color:#330066; font-weight:bold; margin:0 0 25px 0; letter-spacing:0.02em;}

h2 {color:#ff0000; font-weight:bold; margin:0 0 10px 0;}
h2 span { font-style:italic; color:#ccc; font-size:0.7em; text-decoration: line-through}

p { font-size: 0.80em; line-height:1.5em; margin:0 0 10px 0}

.center { text-align:center;}
.center a {color:#333; font-weight:bold;}
.center a:hover {color:#666}

#wrap {width:690px; margin:50px auto; display:block; background:url(../images/wrap-bg.jpg) top left repeat-x; padding:25px;}

#left {width:350px; float:left; margin:0 20px 0 0;}

#bigpic {width:320px; height:340px; float:left; margin:0 0 30px 0; }
#bigpic img { display:block; margin:0 auto; width: 252px; }

#thumbs {height:100px; width:350px; clear:both; display:block;}
#thumbs ul li {height:100px;width:100px;display: inline; padding:0 10px 0 0; float:left;}
#thumbs ul li img {border:1px solid #ccc;}
#thumbs ul li img:hover {cursor:pointer;border:1px solid #ddd;}

p#desc {text-align:center;padding: 10px 0}

img#apple {width:188px; margin:0 auto; display:block}

.b {border:1px solid #ccc;}

.curvey {-moz-border-radius:30px; -webkit-border-radius: 30px;}
```

For HTML

```
<div id="wrap" class="b curvey">
    <h1>Some Super Amazing iPhone Yay</h1>

    <div id="left">

        <div id="bigpic" class="b">
            <img src="images/big/iphone-3-big.jpg" alt="iPod Shuffle 16GB Zoom View" />

            <p id="desc">iPod Shuffle 16GB Zoom View</p>

        </div>

        <div id="thumbs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="images/big/iphone-1-big.jpg" rel="images/small/iphone-1-small.jpg">
                        <img src="images/small/iphone-1-small.jpg" alt="iPod Shuffle Front View In Blue!" />
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="images/big/iphone-2-big.jpg" rel="images/small/iphone-2-small.jpg">
                        <img src="images/small/iphone-2-small.jpg" alt="iPod Shuffle Dual View Grey!" />
                    </a>
                </li
                >
                <li>
                    <a href="images/big/iphone-3-big.jpg" rel="images/small/iphone-3-small.jpg">
                        <img src="images/small/iphone-3-small.jpg" alt="iPod Shuffle 16GB Zoom View" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>


    <h2>&pound;125.99 <span>was &pound;155.99</span></h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 
    ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
    in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
    deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 
    ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

    <img src="images/apple.gif" alt="apple" id="apple" />

    <a href="#" class="button" id="add-to-cart"><span>Add to Basket</span></a>

    <div class="clear"></div>


</div>

<p class="center"><a href="#">&laquo; Back to tutorial at web-design-talk.co.uk ....</a></p>
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide some code? a jsfiddle?

Comment: @JamesNicholson yes http://jsfiddle.net/11mini11/EQBXF/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
#left {
width: 600px;
margin: 0 20px 0 0;
height: 500px;
}

#bigpic {
width: 320px;
height: 340px;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 30px 0;

#thumbs {
height: 400px;
width: 100px;
float: left;
}

#thumbs ul li {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
padding: 0 10px 0 0;
```

Comment: sorry, it didn't work properly on my end :( I mean the alignment that is.

Comment: Show me your code or any sample on which you are working. it's working fine at my end.